HTML Input Time Picker in Chrome on Android truncating options
[view from tablet.]
(https://i.sstatic.net/f55DTGT6.png)
The "Set" button is cut off for the default HTML <input type="time"> on all occasions.
Tried updating chrome.
Tried w3schools  to make sure it was not my styling.
Chrome is updated. Android Version 11
Im guessing the solution is to use some other framework than the default w/ a time picker. But If I dont have to it would be nice.
